# Can I use getters/settings with this in javascript? Does using this.property still trigger the getter?

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter

```
class MyClass {
    constructor () {
         this._value = 1
    }

    increase (e) {
        this.value = this.value + 1;
    }

    get value () {return this._value;}

    set value(value) {
         this._value = value;
    }
}
```

does this not work? I want `increase()` to trigger both the getter and setter (since its getting and setting the value)

Comment: `get value` should be paired with `set value`, not `set scale`

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: oh yeah sorry, scale should have been value

Comment: Yes. This will call both getter and setter. You can even do this.value++ and it'll still call both.

Comment: Surely it will, because there is nothing else than the getter and setter named `value` on this object ...